# Boost lambda with std::find_if does not compile

Tags: boost-lambda, c++

Consider this template member method of some class:

```
template<typename T>
bool elementIsInSharedPtrVector(const T& p_elem, const std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< T > >& p_Vector) const
{
    return (std::find_if(p_Vector.begin(), p_Vector.end(), **boost::lambda::_1 == p_elem) != p_Vector.end());
}
```

The compiler gives this error(besides hundreds of template errors):

```
usr/include/boost/pointee.hpp:30: error: no type named 'element_type' in 'struct SLnAdjW'
```

The type `SLnAdjW` is a POD C struct with a free defined == operator function.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This might be largely irrelevant, but find_if returns an iterator and your function returns a bool - that may add to the noise

Comment: Why do you have `**boost::lambda::_1` shouldn't it just be `*boost::lambda::_1` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're de-referencing _1 twice? The predicate to find_if doesn't take iterators, it takes the underlying value type, in this case boost::shared_pointers.

Comment: Thank you guys! I assumed iterators instead of value types. De-referencing only once is compile clean.